# qiwi api Ошибка python

Tags: python, requests, qiwi

хочу с помощью API совершить перевод денежных средств на другой кошелек.
Возникает проблема, которая приходит в json:

```
{'message': "Invalid Json: Unrecognized token 'id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@50fd882a; line: 1, column: 4]"}
```

Код:

```
def transfer_in_qiwi_wallet(self, amount, number_qiwi_wallet, comment):
    self.url = self.root_url + "sinap/api/v2/terms/99/payments"
    print(self.url)
    self.data = {
        "id":"91111111141111",
        "sum": {
          "amount": amount,
          "currency": "643"
        },
        "paymentMethod": {
          "type":"Account",
          "accountId": "643"
        },
        "comment": comment,
        "fields": {
          "account": number_qiwi_wallet
        }
    }

    json_text = requests.post(self.url, data=self.data, headers=self.header).json()
    print(json_text)
```

Как вызываю:

```
qiwi.transfer_in_qiwi_wallet("100", "+79822304501", "test")
```

[Документация](https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/?shell#p2p)

Comment: По-моему вы неправильно отправляете json, вместо `data=self.data` вроде надо `json=self.data` (а зачем вообще здесь self?)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, заработало. Эта функция часть класса